# What is the difference between these two bubble sort algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am studying algorithms now. And I have searched for the Bubble sort algorithm online, the implementations that I mostly found seem to be over complicated to what I had written myself. Both algorithms work.

Mine is bubbleSort1 and the one that I found in most sources is bubbleSort2.

I have added a counter in the if block. And it seems that the second algorithm has more operations than the first one.

```
static void bubbleSort1(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);

}

static void bubbleSort2(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int temp = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {

                temp = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

For the following array of int : {0, 0, -10, 4, 100, 2, 5, 45, 1, -400, 3, 5, 6}

bubbleSort1 count: 26

bubbleSort2 count: 28

So there is clearly a difference.

Comment: Yours doens't really bubble, but it looks like selection sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Notice that version 2 swaps two neighboring elements (index `j` and `j-1`), while you always compare and swap with your first unsorted element (index `i`).

Comment: There are a bunch of differences. You mostly just need to look at it line-by-line to identify them. Like you can see the upper bound for `i` is `n` in one case and `n-1` in the other case, and `j` goes from `i+1` in one case and `1` in the other case. Figuring out what each algorithm is actually doing on a higher level might require some more thought. Although you wrote the first one, so you should know what that does, and the other one is a well-known algorithm of which there are plenty of explanations available online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your function(*bubbleSort1*) isn't *bubble sort*. In bubble sort, adjacent elements *swap* between themselves.

Secondly, in *bubbleSort2* function, the largest element is placed at the end first, then second largest element is placed at the *end - 1* position and so on. But in *bubbleSort1*, the smallest element is paced at the ***0*** position first, then second smallest element at position ***1*** and so on.

But both of them are ***O(Nˆ2)*** time complexity.